# object mapper giving null in response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am reading the json response and passing it to a objectMapper but the value is not being recognised by the mapper.even though everything is being defined not sure why the data is not being read though I get the json  response from `response.getBody().asString()`,
In the below code i am getting api response as null but getting the json data from `response.getBody().asString())`.I have also mentioned the catalog class for the reference.Also the Response is of type interface here.I am not sure why I am getting null in the getResponse here

```
  GetResponse apiResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody().asString(), 
 GetResponse.class);
 List<catalog> getResponse = apiResponse.getGetResponse();
```

I have below class as GetResponse class

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GetResponse {

    @JsonProperty("getResponse")
    private List<Catalog> getResponse;

    @JsonProperty("def")
    private String def;

    @JsonProperty("abc")
    private String abc;

}
```

Below is the catalog class as well.Here I am defining the color which. is a list.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Catalog {
    @JsonProperty(“color”)
    private String color;
    @JsonProperty(“design”)
    private String design;
}
```

Comment: show us the json response

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]

Comment: {“Response:[{“def”:”hello”,”get”Response:[{“colour”:”Red”,”design”:”plain”}],”abc”:”Good” }]}

Comment: @AbhishekDalakoti add json in question and it seems invalid json `”get”Response`. Add `Catalog` class also

Comment: How are you obtaining this `response` object, and what type is it?

Comment: Response is of type interface.                                                                              public interface Response extends ResponseBody<Response>, ResponseOptions<Response>, Validatable<ValidatableResponse, Response> {
}

Answer (score 0):

the JSON string should be like this :

```
{"getResponse":[],"def":"DEF","abc":"ABC"}
```